# Reading Array at Memory Address

Tags: c

This is for an injected .DLL.

Given the following code:

```
if ( *(volatile unsigned long*)(0x13E81F4+(4 * *(volatile unsigned long*)0x13E81B0)) < 2)
{
    //...
}
```

Is there a way to write that in a more readable fashion, eg:

```
if (array[i] < 2)
{
    //...
}
```

(while still using the desired memory addresses)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
volatile unsigned long *p = (volatile unsigned long *)0x13E81F4;
volatile unsigned long *q = (volatile unsigned long *)0x13E81B0;

if ( p[4 * q[0]] < 2 )
```